# Solving the differential equation $y'=y(1-y^2)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question about solving the differential equation $y'=y(1-y^2)$.

My book says it's $\frac{|y|}{\sqrt{|y^2-1|}}=e^x$.

How do I get this?

My way was:

Let $G(y)=y(1-y^2)$ and $F(x)=1$. If I integrate it I get:

$\int \frac{1}{G(y)}dy=\int \biggl(\frac{1}{y(1-y^2}\biggr)dy=\int \biggl(\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{2(y-1)}-\frac{1}{2(y+1)}\biggr)=-\frac{ln(|y+1|)}{2}+ln(|y|)-\frac{ln(|y-1|)}{2}+C_1$

$\int F(x)dx=x+C_2$

So

$-\frac{ln(|y+1|)}{2}+ln(|y|)-\frac{ln(|y-1|)}{2}=x+C$

$\Leftrightarrow -ln(|y+1|)+2ln(|y|)-ln(|y-1|)=2x+2C$

$\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{y+1}+y^2+\frac{1}{y-1}=\tilde{C}e^{2x}$

I get something different from the solution in the book. What did I miss? And how do I get the solution from above?

Comment: The exponential of a sum is a product, but you've turned the exponential of a the left-hand side--a sum of logarithms--into a sum of the arguments of the logarithms. Instead, the arguments of the logarithms need to be multiplied (after suitable reconstructions).

Comment: I would try $\frac{d}{dy}\ln(y)=\frac{y'}{y}=(1-y^2)$

Comment: As you got, $-\frac{1}{2}\ln(|y+1|)+\ln(|y|)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(|y-1|)=x+C$, we have $$-\frac{1}{2}\ln(|y+1|)+\ln(|y|)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(|y-1|)=\ln\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{|y+1|}}\right)+\ln(|y|)+\ln\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{|y-1|}}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{|y|}{\sqrt{|y^2-1|}}\right)=x+C\implies \frac{|y|}{\sqrt{|y^2-1|}}=ke^x$$

Comment: Alright, so the constant $k$ can be ignored then?

Comment: The thing you left out is this:  there are four nonconstant types of solutions: $y > 1, $   $ 1 > y > 0 ,$  $0 > y > -1,$ $-1 > y$  If you work out the four cases, you won't need absolute value signs;  if desired, you may then see how some of the four formulas might combine into absolute value formulas

Comment: @Tartulop The value of $k$ is actually $\dfrac{|y(0)|}{\sqrt{|y(0)^2-1|}}$ so it depends on $y(0)$.

Answer (score 3):

When you exponentiated a sum of logarithms, you should have obtained a product, not a sum.

Answer (score 1):

You could also treat this as a Bernoulli equation with a third power, giving the substitution $u=y^{-2}$, thus
$$
u'=-2y^{-3}y'=2(1-u)\implies u=1+ce^{-2x}
$$
etc.

Answer (score 1):

as I commented, use of absolute values tends to obscure bifurcations;  there are constant solutions at $y = 1, y = 0, y = -1$

The two  nonconstant solutions with $y > 0$  are any horizontal translates of these (autonomous). Note how one is decreasing from $\infty,$ while the other increases from $0$ to $1$

[image]